# Node.js Date Objects stored in MongoDB as "1970-01-01T00:00:00.001Z"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, datetime, mongoose, compose-db

I have a Node.js application and I'm using Mongoose to interface with MongoDB on Compose.io. Here's some code that should store the current date and time in my database:

```
signup.Volunteer.find({_id : uniqueid.toObjectId()}, function(err, doc){
    var volunteer = doc[0];
    var date = new Date();
    console.log(date.toString());
    //volunteer.time_out is an array
    //defined in Volunteer Schema as: 'time_in : [Date]'
    volunteer.time_in = volunteer.time_in.push(date);
    volunteer.save(function(err){
        ...
    });
});
....
```

If I print these date objects to the console, I get the right date. BUT, when I store the object in my database, it's stored as "1970-01-01T00:00:00.001Z". Is there any idea why this would be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're assigning the return value of `volunteer.time_in.push` back to `volunteer.time_in`.  The return value is the new length of the array, not the array itself.

So change that line to just:

```
volunteer.time_in.push(date);
```

Comment: Wow what a stupid mistake on my side. Really not even worth the post. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

Check the date format in your database. MongoDB date format is YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: Were did you find the date format ?
couldn't find it myself haha